# How to define a not null field for a table of SQLite when I use Anko in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, anko

I hope to define a not null field   for a table of SQLite when I use Anko in Kotlin.

But `DBRecordTable.Category to TEXT NOT NULL` is wrong ,how can I fix it?

**Code**

```
  implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sqlite:$anko_version"

  override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        db.createTable( DBRecordTable.TableNAME , true,
            DBRecordTable._ID to INTEGER + PRIMARY_KEY+ AUTOINCREMENT,
            DBRecordTable.Category to TEXT NOT NULL,    //It's wrong
            DBRecordTable.Content to TEXT,
            DBRecordTable.IsFavorite to INTEGER  +DEFAULT("0"),
            DBRecordTable.IsProtected to INTEGER  +DEFAULT("0"),
            DBRecordTable.CreatedDate to INTEGER
        )
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean about "wrong"? It has syntax error? or runtime?

Comment: Thanks!  it displays `Unresolved reference: NULL` and can't be compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By taking a look at [`sqlTypes.kt`](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/anko/library/static/sqlite/src/main/java/sqlTypes.kt) we can find that the `not null` constraint is defined as following:

> `val NOT_NULL: SqlTypeModifier = SqlTypeModifierImpl("NOT NULL")`

So your code should be:

```
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
    db.createTable( DBRecordTable.TableNAME , true,
        DBRecordTable._ID to INTEGER + PRIMARY_KEY + AUTOINCREMENT,
        DBRecordTable.Category to TEXT + NOT_NULL,
        DBRecordTable.Content to TEXT,
        DBRecordTable.IsFavorite to INTEGER + DEFAULT("0"),
        DBRecordTable.IsProtected to INTEGER + DEFAULT("0"),
        DBRecordTable.CreatedDate to INTEGER
    )
}
```

Comment: `DBRecordTable.Category to TEXT + NOT_NULL` can be compiled, but I'm not sure if it's correct

Comment: Yes, `TEXT + NOT_NULL` is right. It seems to be correct. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

We used these lines of code and it works great table created

```
private val dbName = THE_PATH +"JSANotes.db"
private val dbTable = "Notes"
private val colId = "Id"
private val colTitle = "Title"
private val colContent = "Content"
private val dbVersion = 1

private val CREATE_TABLE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + dbTable + " (" + colId + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + colTitle + " TEXT, " + colContent + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
private var db: SQLiteDatabase? = null

init {
    val dbHelper = DatabaseHelper(context)
    db = dbHelper.writableDatabase
}
```

This site will help with a lot of SQLite questions [LINK](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/tables/create_table.php)

We do not use the NOT NULL we do this in place of NOT NULL

```
            if(edtContent.text.toString().equals("")){
            error("ENTER Content")
            edtContent.requestFocus()
            return@setOnClickListener
        }
```

You can also test for length the error message shows in a Text View at the bottom of the Activity with this code

```
        fun error(msg:String){
        object : CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                tvError.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                tvError.setText(msg)
            }
            override fun onFinish() {
                tvError.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                tvError.setText("")
            }
        }.start()
    }
```